# searchBarCancelButtonClicked delegate method is not called. Is there any way to call?

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

UIViewController to implement a view to placing an UITableView UISearchBar and being implemented. But you can not call searchBarCancelButtonClicked. Do not know what the reason.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  My view controller is the search bar's delegate, and it adopts the UISearchBarDelegate protocol.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Everything should be set up properly. All other delegate methods are getting called, but this one does not. I would be happy if a reason is found.

Comment: Check this question. It helped me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004438/uisearchbar-delegate-not-responding-to-cancel-button

Comment: Thank you *derpoliuk*, that's what happened to me!

Answer (score 11):

The reason why searchBarCancelButtonClicked does not fire may be because your UISearchBar does not show the Cancel button. You can display the Cancel button like this:

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
```

I had the same problem and making the Cancel button show made searchBarCancelButtonClicked fire as expected.

Comment: In my case I was clicking on the x in the bar window --> that is not the cancel button. [I was thinking it was...] Using this line of code caused the word 'Cancel' to show up to the right of my bar, and then I realized my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Ensure that your UIViewController is set as the delegate of your UISearchBar, and that it adopts the UISearchBarDelegate protocol.

Comment: that's the way I have it... all other delegate methods work, just this one doesn't get called, might be a bug of the sdk

Comment: @samiq I seem to have this problem too. This is in iOS 7!

Comment: Added `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self` and the method was called. Thank you.

Comment: @Isuru I am stuck with the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal This was so long ago, man. I honestly don't remember what I did. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
   // This method has been called when u enter some text on search or Cancel the search.
   // so make some condition for example:

   if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText==nil) {
        // Nothing to search, empty result.
        searching = NO;
        [mytableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see "Cancel" button calls that method... :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case was an uncontrolled userInteractionEnabled=NO

Answer (score 1):

`searchController.searchBar.delegate = self`, not just `searchController.delegate = self`

Answer (score 1):

The real reason for me was that i thought the small x button was the meant cancel button, but it's not... if you are having the same issue i faced use the below code

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            searchRecords.removeAll()
            searchTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line remove UISearchController transparent view

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in viewDidLoad. In my case sometimes Cancel button action delegate "searchBarCancelButtonClicked" has triggered and sometimes hasn't ( just keyboard dismissed and cancel button become not active), after adding this everything started working as expected.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2

I had the same problem and had to set the definesPresentationContext property to true before the searchBarCancelButtonClicked method would work.

```
 definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: Please explain how this relates to the question.

Comment: I don't know, how this relates to the question. But in my case    self.definesPresentationContext = true works like a champ.

Answer (score -3):

I ran into the same problem when I had a UISearchBar inside of a UIScrollView. As I understand the question you had it inside a UITableView, which is a subclass of UIScrollView.

What helped in my case was setting

```
tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

Seems the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method doesn't work well with that set to `YES`, which is the default setting.

Comment: That method doesn't seem to exist

Comment: My bad, I accidentally referenced the searchBar instead of the UIScrollView subclass. It does exist there since iOS 2.0: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches